# Replica - MongoDB EC2 instances

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-replication

Added 3 EC2 instances in in AWS cloud.
Installed 3 MongoDB instances in 3 different instances and all are running fine.

I am adding replication for the same DBs.

below are the steps i followed:

1. sudo service mongod start --sslPEMKeyFile "/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem" --sslMode "requireSSL" --replSet "myReplSet" ( in all 3 mongo instances)
2. config = {_id : "myReplSet" , members: [{_id: 0, host:"ip-10-0-0-68:27017"},{_id: 1, host:"ip-10-0-0-247:27017"},{_id: 2, host:"ip-10-0-0-148:27017"}]}
3. rs.initiate(config)

Error as below:

```
   MongoDB Enterprise > rs.initiate(config)
   {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "This node was not started with the replSet option",
    "code" : 76,
    "codeName" : "NoReplicationEnabled"
  }
```

**EDIT**

I added same security groups and Elastic IP for all 3 instances.
All 3 are new DBs.
Now I am getting error as:

```
   {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "'ip-10-0-0-148:27017' has data already, cannot initiate set.",
"code" : 110,
"codeName" : "CannotInitializeNodeWithData"
   }
```

**EDIT-2**

Config file for one the servers:

```
    # mongod.conf

    # for documentation of all options, see:
    #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
    dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
    journal:
    enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # how the process runs
     processManagement:
    fork: true  # fork and run in background
     pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

    # network interfaces
    net:
    port: 27017
    #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,13.58.225.174,13.58.180.226  # Listen to local   interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


    #security:

    #operationProfiling:

    replication:
      replSetName: rs0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it works fine.

1. rs.initialize()
2. rs.add()
3. rs.add()

i reffed here:
https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-mongodb-replica-set/

Answer (score 1):

The service start command does not accept parameters. So

```
sudo service mongod start --sslPEMKeyFile "/etc/ssl/mongodb.pem" --sslMode "requireSSL" --replSet "myReplSet"
```

Is equivalent to

```
sudo service mongod start
```

If you want to add those settings to the `mongod` configuration, you will need to edit `/etc/mongod.conf` to add them in. Since the names of some options vary between the command line and the configuration file, you should take a look at the [Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) documentation to ensure you use the correct settings.

**EDIT**

Based on your edits and the error message, it appears the `mongod` process (`ip-10-0-0-148:27017`) already has data on it. You cannot add a `mongod` process that already has data to a replica set. You can, however, initiate the replica set on a `mongod` process that already has data. You should connect to that `mongod` process and run the `rs.initiate()` there. Then you run `rs.add()` to add the remaining, empty, `mongod` processes to the replica set.

*Note: MongoDB does offer [MongoDB Cloud Manager](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/cloud-manager) and [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) which can do some or all of this for you. However, they are not free, so its up to you if you want to use them.*

Comment: I have tried with sudo service mongod start and also sudo service mongod start --replSet rs0

Comment: @CHowdappaM, there is a `mongod` configuration file, it is typically located in `/etc/mongod.conf`, you need to edit this file with your favorite text editor. I prefer `nano`, so the command would be `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: I have added config file.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an empty replica set or are you attempting to convert a standalone to a replica set?

Comment: To a replicaset